# получить event по событию

Tags: angularjs

```js
let module = angular.module("myModule", []);


module.controller("myController", function() {
  ctrl = this;

    ctrl.rows = [ {first:1,second:2,third:3,fouth:4,fifth:5},                              
                    {first:1,second:2,third:3,fouth:4,fifth:5},
                    {first:1,second:2,third:3,fouth:4,fifth:5},
                    {first:1,second:2,third:3,fouth:4,fifth:5},
                    {first:1,second:2,third:3,fouth:4,fifth:5},                             
                    {first:1,second:2,third:3,fouth:4,fifth:5},
                    {first:1,second:2,third:3,fouth:4,fifth:5},
                    {first:1,second:2,third:3,fouth:4,fifth:5},                             
                    {first:1,second:2,third:3,fouth:4,fifth:5},
                    {first:1,second:2,third:3,fouth:4,fifth:5}];

    ctrl.onKeydown = function (event) {
      console.log('event',event);
    }
  
    angular.element(document.body).on('keydown', ctrl.onKeydown);
});
```

```css
.height-150{
  height:150px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.bold{
  font-weight:bold;
}
.width-15>td{
  width:15px;
}
```

```html
<script 
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  
<div ng-app="myModule">

  <div ng-controller="myController as mc">
  
    <div>
      <button >button</button>
      <button >button</button>
      <button >button</button>
      <button >button</button>
      <button >button</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="height-150">

      <table border=1>
      
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="bold">1</th>
             <th class="bold">2</th>
             <th class="bold">3</th>
             <th class="bold">4</th>
             <th class="bold">5</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
           <tr class="width-15" ng-repeat="row in mc.rows">
             <td>{{row.first}}</td>
             <td>{{row.second}}</td>
             <td>{{row.third}}</td>
             <td>{{row.fouth}}</td>
             <td>{{row.fifth}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

      </table>
      
    </div>  
    
  </div>   
  
</div>
```

Comment: `<table ng-keydown="$ctrl.functionName($event)" ...`

Comment: хотелось бы с такой конструкцией `angular.element(elem).on('keydown', onKeydown)` т.к. во всем проекте так сделано, если это возможно, там вопрос то в другом, это я пока пытаюсь воспроизвести ситуацию в работающем примере на jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот - простейший пример того как нужно "подписываться на событие" средствами angularjs:

```js
let module = angular.module("myModule", []);
module.controller("myController", function() {
    this.functionName = (ev, idx) => console.log(`myEvent ${idx}`, ev);
});
```

```css
table { margin: 1em; width: 50%; }
:focus { outline: 1px dashed green; }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="myModule">
      <div ng-controller="myController as vm">
          <table ng-keypress="vm.functionName($event, 1)" border="1" tabindex="1"><tbody><tr><td>12</td></tr></tbody></table>
          <table ng-keypress="vm.functionName($event, 2)" border="1" tabindex="2"><tbody><tr><td>34</td></tr></tbody></table>       
      </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: понял, спасибо, переделал код вопроса - он отрисовывает таблицу, но не консолит event, не подскажете почему?

Comment: клавиатурное событие не может произойти над таблицей - нужно поле для ввода

Comment: а в проекте работает(используется в навигации по строкам таблицы кнопками Вверх Вниз) и я пытаюсь создать тут по аналогии упрощенный вариант, чтобы решить проблему в навигации...

Comment: основано на `angular.element(ctrl.elem).on('keydown', ctrl.onKeyupNavig);`, где elem - div в котором таблица, и event.target - <tr>

Comment: вот сейчас работает над таблицей, только здесь почему-то вместо body нельзя другой элемент ДОМа поставить, а в проекте можно, ну и соответственно сложнее достать метрики какого-нибудь элемента, по которым и был у меня вопрос

Comment: @Валера, давай отдохнём от angularjs и пофантазируем вот о чём: есть на страничке 2 таблицы с твоим 1,2,3,4,5 и сидит пользователь, бьёт по клавиатуре. Как, по-твоему, браузер должен определять над какой из табличек происходит событие keydown?

Comment: я думаю, что надо сначала кликнуть на одну из них(фокус поставить?) и после этого браузер будет слушать событие на этой таблице/элементе, по крайней мере, у меня сейчас так(в ангуляре, правда))), я в разработке недавно, и многого ещё не знаю, хотел тему про фокус на странице в ближайшее время погуглить.

Comment: вот [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/focus-blur#%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5-tabindex) можно почитать. для нагладности я добавил в ответ tabindex-ы

Answer (score 0):

удалось получить event при наступлении события нажатия клавиши с клавиатуры над document.body, плохо, что не получилось поставить обработчик на div, например, хотя в реальном приложении  - работает